# How to set ListView Row Height in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to set height of the `ListView` in XAML file for iOS Device using below mentioned code and bindings.

1. I've used observable collection to notify when the property value is updated and it is getting notified and sets the correct value but it is not being reflected in iOS Simulator or device but that works fine with Android & Windows Phone Devices.

```
<ListView  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionAnswerList,Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData,Mode=TwoWay}"                   
        HasUnevenRows="true" 
        RowHeight="{Binding Custom_height,Mode=TwoWay}"  
        BackgroundColor="Silver" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

2. I've tried to set Row Height of List View statically as well but that also doesn't work.
3. I haven't given any height and set Grid RowDefinition height = "*" but then also it doesn't set the height of the ListView instead it overlaps the details on the next ListView row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

On `iOS`, when you set `ListView.HasUnevenRows` to `true`, you also have to set the `Cell.Height` **for each cell** property too, as the renderer can not infer it from the content.

You can also use `ListView.RowHeight` like you do in your example, for even rows. In that case, do not set `ListView.HasUnevenRows` (or set it to `false`).

Answer (score 8):

Try using a StackLayout instead of a ListView:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I have spent days searching for this. A way to make a list without being stuck with the annoying default system list. Thank you so much.

Comment: This solution is an extremely good alternative to a ListView with HasUnevenRows="true", which is very problematic on iOS as the rows can't dynamically adjust its height based on the content. For our case, the only thing that is missing when using this alternate solution is the pull-to-refresh feature, and we needed to wrap the StackLayout with a ScrollView.

Comment: The biggest problem with using a StackLayout is if your list is large and changes a lot.  There is a huge time hit.